# Using Import Wizard with Access - No null values

Tags: ssms, database-administration, sql-import-wizard

I am trying to import a table from Access to SSMS using the Import Wizard but when I do the resulting table has a lot of empty strings instead of the NULL values that I am expecting.

How do I make sure that any null values in Access come through correctly as NULL values in SSMS?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This doesn't feel like a programming question; it feels like it belongs in SuperUser or DBA. (There's no coding question here). Voting to migrate to DBA.

Comment: Apologies, I was looking through other questions and pushed the Ask Question button.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an obvious way of how to move the question to the correct topic?

Comment: No problem -- this seems like a question that's well-written enough to be answerable; it justs needs to be in the right place.

Comment: As far as moving it.. the only two solutions are (1) wait until it attracts enough close vote (where they specifically voted to close+migrate to dba), or (2) go to dba.stackexchange.com and repost it there. I'm impatient; I'd go visit the other site.

Comment: Thank you :) Will repost now